# How to reduce TTFB time?

Tags: performance, cloudflare, cdn, digital-ocean

I have [a website](https://www.funfun.io) hosted by DigitalOcean (1GB Memory/20GB Disk/LON1) and CloudFlare.

Lots of external librairies were from `cdnjs.com`, which worked well in Europe and US, but they were not stable in China. So I decided to host all of them in my DigitalOcean server.

Then, I check the speed **from China** by Google Chrome Dev Tools, I notice that `TTFB` (from `10s` to `1s`) are really unacceptable:

[image]

Does anyone know if I could do something (eg, configuring the DigitalOcean droplet) to reduce the TTFB time?

Comment: Page caching may help. Latency is something that can be mitigated depending on the situation.

Comment: What I care most is the first time people open my site, where all the libraries need to be loaded. I'm afraid page caching would not help this stage...

Answer (score 1):

You can TTFB to about 20ms if you cache the page on CloudFlare. Set up a page rule similar to:

[image]

Then after the page is cached on the edge, the next page loads will have TTFB of about 20ms:

[image]

I can't promise that speed in China. It's a known bottleneck. You can pay them for faster networking though.

Comment: Will this affect the **first** load of the page for a user? This is what I care most...

Comment: Yes. Look in my second screen shot - cache was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare is not active per default in China. There is only the Enterprise (several thousands dollar/month) plan with access to China pop.

Beside that, you should be aware that too much cache can have side effect. If you using a cms like Wordpress or Magento, too much cache on edge will not be aware of login cookie, different block that eventually needs dynamic content, etc.

For a static website, it's excelent. For dynamic website you should be aware of this.

If China is your main targe, just register to alibaba cloud and spin up a VM behind the Great Firewall. But first remember, to host a website (or event to route trafic on port 80) you need China license (ICP).

Also you can spin up a VM in alibaba cloud eg in Bejing, and with geo dns, pick up the static files directly from chinese hosted vm.